# Monero technology information

Tags: cryptography

While this SE site is a good source for getting specific questions answered, where can I go to gain good background knowledge and learn technical details about Monero?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a pretty solid introductory website over at http://moneroinfo.org. I typically point people there if they are completely brand new.

Comment: That page doesn't load for me...

Answer (score 7):

A good place to start would be https://getmonero.org/home, try looking at the various topics under Knowledge Base. If you have further specific questions, you can ask on Reddit, IRC, or here.

Answer (score 5):

Here! Just ask what you would like to know, or browse the other questions. Searching by tags is a useful way to find a lot about a certain topic.

Answer (score 5):

The best information can still be found on the CryptoNote website. (CryptoNote is a cryptocurrency platform from which Monero descends.)

You can find a well-illustrated explanation of the general principles here: https://cryptonote.org/inside/

Low-level technical descriptions/standards can be found here: https://cryptonote.org/standards/

Note that Monero is more and more diverging from this, so not everything will apply directly. The overall principles are the same, though - at least until Confidential Transactions (CT) is deployed in Monero.

Answer (score 2):

I would also suggest a peek at https://getmonero.org/research-lab/

This page has links to the CN whitepaper, the CN whitepaper annotated by the MRL team and a full review by Surae Noether.

It also links you to https://lab.getmonero.org/